# Select2 default search box not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using  select2 js
I am just using default function, but the default search box is showing in disabled mode. i am not able to type anything in it.

My code is

```
<select id="type" name="type" class="form-control select2-use">
    <option value="">select type</option>
    <option value="U">User</option>
    <option value="A">Admin</option>
</select>

$('.select2-use').select2({
    placeholder: "Select",
    allowClear: true
});
```

I have included the select2.min.css and select2.min.js in my HTML page.

There is no js errors.

I am using this in Bootstrap modal div in which i load a HTML page

Comment: Can you replicate it in `snippet` or `fiddle`?

Comment: To me works fine, look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/40eemy84/9/

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi Works for me as well except searchbox

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi I am using this in Bootstrap modal div in which i load a HTML page

Comment: @SunilPachlangia : please provide jsfiddle. there might be minor mistake,which can be resolved by actual code.Also add particular versions of respective Js files.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia, your code works fine to all of us. Please provide a fiddle, cus maybe another element is causing this issue!

Answer (score 16):

Your code looks ok: https://jsfiddle.net/3tfjn9zb/1/

Are you using it in a bootstrap modal? If so: try to remove `tabindex="-1"` from the modal div.

Comment: I try this as well but no success

Comment: Can you give us more context about your issue? Are you using this in a specific div/page? As you can see in the Fiddle, there is nothing wrong with your code (if you include jquery, select2 css & js).

Comment: I am using this in Bootstrap modal div in which i load a HTML page

Comment: I have re-created it in a modal. Like you can see, everything works, it's important to remove `tabindex="1"` [watch the example here](https://jsfiddle.net/3tfjn9zb/1/)

Answer (score -1):

**Just add Your Js file**

```
$('select').select2();
```